# How to submit a form and use the result in javascript triggered by the submit button?

Tags: javascript, ruby, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a `form_tag` form that I want to submit in order to get the values. These same values I want to use in a javascript that is triggered by the same submit button I use for the form.

What I want to do is to first submit the form and then call the javascript.
My submit function looks like that:

```
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :onclick => "sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;" %>
```

but it only calls the javascript and doesn't submit the form. 
If I do something like this: 
 `:onclick => "submit();sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;"` 
then I only submit the form but don't call the javascript.

Can I somehow say "trigger this javascript after the form is submitted(using the result of the submission)?

My javascript looks like that:

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() { { options } , requestCallback); }
```

Comment: If you submit the form any javascript functionality on the current page is pretty much gone, as it reloads the page. If you don't submit the form, you're not getting the data you're after. Sounds like you need ajax.

Comment: I don't know how to do the ajax call, so I guess I will need to go with the page reload. Can I activate the javascript after the page reload, limited to only when the page was reloaded due to the form submission?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return false which prevents the default action of the submit button.

Try:

```
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :onclick => "sendRequestToRecipients();" %>
```

Comment: Removing return false lets the form submit (and the page refreshes), but the javascript doesn't load. What I want is the form to submit and the javascript to load right after.